# How to get the correct area of each triangle of a tessellated (scaled) cube using the Python API?

Tags: python, coordinates

When I add a cube to the scene with dimensions 2x2x2, and run `cube_obj.data.calc_loop_triangles()` followed by `list(cube_obj.data.loop_triangles)[0].area`, I get what I would expect, an area of 2 (the face area is 4, so the triangle should be 2, which is great).
If I scale the cube, doubling its dimension to 4x4x4 I would expect the area of each triangle to become 4, but the area attribute remains 2...
How do I workaround this and get the area of the triangle in global terms using the API?

I understand that I could just get each triangle local coords vertices, pre-multiply by the object matrix_world: `obj.matrix_world @ obj.data.vertices[i].co` and from there calculate the area. But I assume the API already gives me that, I just don't know what to call.

Thanks for your attention.